# Modal PopUp not displaying in chrome

Tags: modalpopupextender

hi i have some problem in displaying popup as when i implemented,its working perfectly in firefox and IE but not it chrome.[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2960ed3989.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2960ed3989.jpg)

also check the link.how to solve this problem in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set z-index:100000 in panel display option.

Answer (score 1):

Hey your chrome browser might be preventing the pop up. Why dont you enable the popups in google chrome, and then see the results. Google chrome has popups disabled by default. This link might be help you in enabling and disabling the pop ups in google chrome.
http://tech.konnectingtheworld.com/2010/09/enable-disable-popup-window-in-chrome/

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, i had three extenders on the page and some were working and some not. Try adding a drop shadow to the popup and see how chrome reacts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

set the modal popup to Css Class ex:

```
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
```

Set a lesser z-index for modalBackground

```
.modalBackground
{
   ...
   z-index:999;
}
```

You may need to inspect the actual z-index values for the elements created by the extender.
You can use firebug on FF, Dom Inspector in Chrome, or Developer ToolBar in IE

Answer (score 0):

just set z-index:100000 in panel display option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my CSS. I have been using Chrome for quite sometime now, so it might work for you:

```css
.popUpStyle
{
   font: normal 11px auto "Trebuchet MS", Verdana;    
   background-color: #ffffff;
   color: #4f6b72; 
   padding:6px;      
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   opacity: 0.8;
}
```